# AngularJS (ng-grid) order by original index

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

When the grid is initially rendered, it follows the ordering of the list (model) behind it.  How would one revert to that same natural ordering after a sort by column has occurred?

Answer (score 0):

Within an ng-repeater you could set a custom data attribute to `{{$index}}`

```
<li class="sortable" ng-repeat="item in items" data-index="{{$index}}">
```

Then when the DOM is manipulated to produce your column sort the index when rendered will be preserved within `data-index`